# implementation of a b-spline curve n points

Tags: java, python, math, spline

hi i'm trying to implement the n points spline curve, but it seems like it requires some calculus knowledge.
Unfortunately I did not follow the calculation of high school.

I would like a function that takes a list of points x and y
and generate an interpolation like the following image.

[image]
I don't know if it's b-spline or bezier. I think it is the first.

I know java and python to draw points, but any language that is easy to understand.
I don't want to use third party libraries or functions

```
Example pseudocode:
float [] [] inter_points [] [2]
float [] spline (float [] x, float y []) {
// algorithm here
return inter_points;
};

draw_ellipse (points [] [0], points [1], 2,2)
```

Comment: A B-spline is just a curve made up of one or more Beziers.  The math is the same.

Comment: If you don't follow the math, then use a library.  That's what they're for.

Comment: libraries limit me a lot

Comment: No, they don't.  They save time, so you can focus on solving your problem, instead of reinventing solutions to problems that were solved in 1965.